# Webscraping with http shows "Web page blocked"

Tags: python, http, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape http website using proxies and when I am trying to extract text, it shows as "Web page Blocked". How could I avoid this error?

My code is as follows

```
url = "http://campanulaceae.myspecies.info/"

proxy_dict = { 
          'http'  : "174.138.54.49:8080", 
          'https' : "174.138.54.49:8080"
        }

page = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy_dict)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

I get below output when I am trying to output text from the website.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Web Page Blocked</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta content="NO-CACHE" http-equiv="PRAGMA"/>
<meta content="initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
........
<body bgcolor="#e7e8e9">
<div id="content">
<h1>Web Page Blocked</h1>
<p>Access to the web page you were trying to visit has been blocked in accordance with company policy. Please contact your system administrator if you believe this is in error.</p>
```

Comment: Do you mean “Web scraping”?

Comment: As the message says, "Please contact your system administrator if you believe this is in error." Did you try that?

Comment: @barny - Is this seriously the first time you've seen someone post a question about *"Web Scrapping"*

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not specify a user-agent for the request headers.
Quite often, sites block requests that come from robot-like sources.
Try it like this:

```py
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxy_dict)
```

Comment: I am still facing the same output "Web page Blocked".

Comment: @anonymous13 try to remove the proxy. Perhaps they are blacklisted.

Comment: If I remove proxies I get below error "Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden"

Comment: @anonymous13 did you remove ```proxies=proxy_dict``` from request arguments?

Comment: Yes, I did. When I remove the proxies I got the above error. I tried using other proxies nothing seems to work.

Comment: @anonymous13 just checked this proxy: ```proxy_dict = {'http': 'http://89.250.221.106:53281', 'https': 'https://89.250.221.106:53281'}``` and it works. Apparently the problem is in your proxy and do not forget to make sure that the proxy supports https

Comment: @anonymous13 if the answer helped you - mark it with a decision

Comment: It was working for a while and when I tried to refresh the session and run the code , it shows proxy error again.

Comment: @anonymous13 because you cannot use the same proxy all the time, you need to change them. Google lists of free proxies and try.